# R shows wrong encoding in data.table, but correct in vector

Tags: r, unicode, data.table

Does anyone know why this happens? I.e. why Unicode character is not displayed correctly within a data table row, but correctly when contained in a vector (data table column)?

```
>test.dt

>fuel    box         seller.name
>1: Gasoline Manual Michels S<U+00E0>rl

> test.dt[,seller.name]
>[1] "Michels Sàrl"
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your locale is set correctly. Try this:

```
library(data.table)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "") # set character type locale to native
df = data.table(id = 1, name = c("Michels Sàrl"),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If that doesn't work, you may be running into a known bug in R on Windows; for another instance of this bug see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720368/6233565

For a work-around, try this:

```
library(corpus)
print.corpus_frame(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, I can see characters now with corpus library. Though it does not solve my problem with characters when saving the data table either as .csv or .txt :(

Comment: Right, that's a related bug; currently it's not possible to write UTF-8 data on windows. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734577/6233565

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example, it's showing normal. Please find below

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(id = 1, name = c("Michels Sàrl"),stringsAsFactors = F)
>df
   id         name
1:  1 Michels Sàrl
```

Comment: No, still "Michels S<U+00E0>rl" for me. So it is related to my R/laptop settings?

Comment: May be.. Can you try the same lines on R 32/64 bit console and see? Not on r studio console

Comment: A bit different result there. In R 3.4.2 64-bit version "Michels S?rl".

Comment: I tried myself on R console, it's giving normal result.. Even as data.frame type